# replacing failed HDD in Lacie 2big

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, nas

I have a Lacie 2big Network, 2 x 1 TB in mirror. One of them failed 3 days ago. It produces a clicking sound, the Raid status shows endless "Synchronizing".

If I buy a new HDD, same type, and replace in the failed slot, will the new empty drive synchronize with old functioning drive?

Or do I have to reformat the whole unit after replacing 1 drive? I want to know if I am going to lose the data on the functioning drive in the process?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're doing RAID 1, if you replace the drive with the exact model as as the other drive - it will rebuild the array and clone the data from the existing hard drive.